TFDBatchMove not closing file after text read
I'm using the C++Builder VCL class TFDBatchMove with TFDBatchMoveTextReader to import a CSV file. So far, everything works fine, I read the CSV file and write it into a TFDMemTable, no problems there.
Now, I want to save the TFDMemTable back to the same CSV file I read from (overwrite it). So, I use another TFDBatchMove with a TFDBatchMoveTextWriter.
When calling TFDBatchMove::Execute() function, I get the error that it can't open the file:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Isn't TFDBatchMoveTextReader closing the file after reading?
How can I force TFDBatchMoveTextReader to close the file?
The only working solution I have come up with is to delete the TFDBatchMoveTextReader instance after importing the CSV file.

"Isn't TFDBatchMoveTextReader closing the file after reading?" - TFDBatchMove::Execute() closes the Reader before exiting, which in turn should be closing the file, yes. Are you sure something else isn't accessing the file? Perhaps an antivirus/antimalware? Have you tried using SysInternals' Process Monitor or Process Explorer to see who is actually opening the file?

@RemyLebeau Thank you. After a proper reboot, the file closed properly and now it works fine.
